# Reading user's input from a JOptionPane and store it in a text file

Tags: java, input, joptionpane

I want to read user's input (user's nickname) from a JOptionPane and then store that input into a new txt file. Also, I want the entered information to update itself in the text file every time a new user enters his nickname. Thank you very much in advance for the help! Here is my code:

```
private static class testItApp implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String filename = "scoreboard.txt";

        try {    
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(filename);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your nickname:");
            output.println("kjkjbkj");
            output.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't change your question in a way which influences the current answer. Since MadProgrammers answer refers to your current code, it should stay in your question.

Comment: What actual problem are you having with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog` returns the value the user entered into the field or `null` if the canceled the dialog.  Assign and check the return result

```
String nickName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your nickname:");
if (nickName != null) {
    // Save it...
}
```

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and [`JOptionPane#showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) for more details

Comment: Ok, it worked. Thank you very much! But the only problem now is that the entered input is not updating itself in the text file, it overwrites every time a new nickname is typed.

Comment: Don't use `PrintWriter`, use [`FileWriter(String, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean))